# Html DropDownList helper does not select default value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am trying to create a dropdownlist of months, that renders with the current month selected:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Month",
                    new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToDictionary<int, string>(
                        i => System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)
                            ), "Value", "Key", DateTime.Now.Month));
```

This builds the list just fine, but it always renders with January selected.

What am I doing wrong here?

HTML output:

```
<select name="Info.Month" id="dLMonth-451" data-val-required="The Month field is required." data-val-number="The field Month must be a number." data-val="true">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2010/07/aspnet-mvc-htmldropdownlist-not-showing.html

Answer (score 0):

Code works for me on MVC4/.Net 4.  What version of .Net and MVC are you using?
could add some of the HTML output?

Comment: Also using MVC4/.Net 4

Comment: I cannot comment on your code above at the mo, but this is my code: <br/>`<select id="Month" name="Month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option selected="selected" value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>`<br/>  Do you have data annotations on this field?

Comment: No it's just a simple field

Comment: You have some data validation code on your html though, I guess you have a Month field in your model?  Could you just try changing the code you have in your view to `@Html.DropDownList("MonthXXXXX",....`